# Use a java class from a referenced project on the server-side?

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT project, and I want to use some classes server-side from another project:

```
MyServerProject
    com.me.myserverproject.server.Horse

SomeSupportProject
    com.me.somesupportproject.server.Animal
```

and MyServerProject Horse.java looks like:

```
class Horse extends Animal {
}
```

In eclipse, I have MyServerProject referencing the SomeSupportProject project. All compiles fine, and GWT Compile runs fine too, no errors.

When I deploy MyServerProject to a local instance, it immediately throws a NoClassDefFoundError error on "Animal.java":

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/me/somesupportproject/server/Animal
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

I marked SomeSupportProject as exported in the eclipse project properties. But it seems like the class file for Animal.java is not getting exported upon deploy. Do we need to do something special here to get that to work?

I must be missing something really obvious since this is pretty basic stuff. I have clientside java files being referenced just fine, which I think is the trickier case. But these are all server-side classes, thought it would be simpler,

Thanks

------- Update: Project Setup ---------------

Some notes on my environment:

Using eclipse, and the two projects are side by side. I'm not using Ant or Maven. I have eclipse set to build automatically, so not getting any compiler errors there. To actually compile for a deploy, I tried right clicking "MyServerProject", choose Google -> GWT Compile. I set output to "all". I don't get any compile errors. The output does not mention any warnings.

After GWT Compile is complete, I right-click the project again, choose Run As -> Web Application. This is what throws the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for the class found in the SomeSupportProject project.

If there any specifics that would help just let me know.

--------- Final Update: Solved -----------------

After working on this some more, it seems we just can't add a project reference and get server-side classes to come across in the deployed top-level project. Instead, I linked to the "src" folder in SomeSupportProject. This allows things to still compile as normal, but when you deploy your project, all the classes are found without issue.

So this was really an app-engine issue, should have tagged it under there instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify how your project is set up eclipse/GPE with ant or maven?

Comment: Ok just update with some notes on my setup.

Comment: You probably chose to reference to the old project but did not include the old project in your source path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this some more, it seems we just can't add a project reference and get server-side classes to come across in the deployed top-level project. Instead, I linked to the "src" folder in SomeSupportProject. This allows things to still compile as normal, but when you deploy your project, all the classes are found without issue.

So this was really an app-engine issue, should have tagged it under there instead.

Thanks!